# error SqException

Tags: java, mysql

Saludos estoy realizando un count basico con **Java** y **MySql**, tengo la siguiente clase que me permite conectar a MySql:

```
package sriConsummer;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
public class ConexionMySQL {

    // Librería de MySQL
    public String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";

    // Nombre de la base de datos
    public String database = "sri";

    // Host
    public String hostname = "localhost";

    // Puerto
    public String port = "3306";

    // Ruta de nuestra base de datos (desactivamos el uso de SSL con "?useSSL=false")
    public String url = "jdbc:mysql://" + hostname + ":" + port + "/" + database + "?useSSL=false";

    // Nombre de usuario
    public String username = "root";

    // Clave de usuario
    public String password = "toor";

    public Connection conectarMySQL() {
        Connection conn = null;

        try {
            Class.forName(driver);
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return conn;
    }

}
```

ahora tengo mi clase principal donde realizo mi select:

```
package sriConsummer;

import java.sql.*;

public class Principal {
    public static void main(String[] argumentos){

        final ConexionMySQL SQL = new ConexionMySQL();
        final Connection conn = SQL.conectarMySQL();
        final String query = " SELECT count(id) AS total from sri.base_catastro WHERE DESCRIPCION_PROVINCIA='AZUAY' ";
        Statement st = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query);
        System.out.println(rs.getInt(1)+" totales");

    }
}
```

Ahora el error que genera es:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation
>   problems:     Unhandled exception type SQLException   Unhandled exception
>   type SQLException     Unhandled exception type SQLException
>
> at sriConsummer.Principal.main(Principal.java:11)

**Actualización:**

He agregado un try de la siguiente manera:

```
    try {
        PreparedStatement st = conn.prepareStatement(query);
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery();
        System.out.println(rs.getInt(1)+" totales");
        conn.close();
        rs.close();
        st.close();
    } catch(SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

El error que genera:

> ```
> java.sql.SQLException: Before start of result set
>   at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:129)
>   at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97)
>   at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:89)
>   at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:63)
>   at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.result.ResultSetImpl.checkRowPos(ResultSetImpl.java:484)
>   at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.result.ResultSetImpl.getObject(ResultSetImpl.java:1283)
>   at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.result.ResultSetImpl.getInt(ResultSetImpl.java:786)
>   at sriConsummer.Principal.main(Principal.java:15)
> ```

Gracias cualquier sugerencia.

Comment: me parece que te falta un throws.. no soy experto yo tampoco, pero por lo que dice el error es eso...

Comment: Pon un try-catch para ver que error sql te da exactamente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

usa la funcion next de tu ResultSet, el cual toma todos los resultados de tu consulta(en tu caso solo un resultado) ej:

```
while(rs.next()) {
   System.out.println(rs.getInt(1)+" totales");
}
```

Nota no te olvides de cerrar el Statement y la Connection

Comment: En efecto eso era lo que faltaba, era tan simple..!!

Answer (score -1):

Rodea con try-catch las tres últimas líneas del main (o todo el código del main, si lo prefieres).

```
try {
    Statement st = conn.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query);
    System.out.println(rs.getInt(1)+" totales");
} catch(SQLException e) {
    e.pritnStackTrace();
}
```

Los métodos `createStatement` de java.sql.Connection, `executeQuery` de Statement y `getInt` de ResultSet lanzan excepciones. El error que tienes lo dice claramente:

> Unhandled exception type SQLException

y te da la primera línea - 11, que es:

`Statement st = conn.createStatement();`

Saludos.

P.D. Te falta cerrar la conexión (y con esto el Statement y el resultSet).

Comment: Gracias he actualizado mi pregunta agregando un try adicional tambien he cerrado conexiones, statement y resulset..pero genera un SQLException

Comment: Claro, hay que llamar `next`